# undefined reference to `atexit - bluez compilation

Tags: c++, bluez, atexit

I am encountering this issue, when i try to cross-compile bluez-4.101, to mipsel-linux target.

```
plugins/bluetoothd-hciops.o: In function `init_device':
hciops.c:(.text+0xadc0): undefined reference to `atexit'
hciops.c:(.text+0xadc8): undefined reference to `atexit'
```

Following are the compiler options and linker options that are specified

-lstdc++ 
-L has the path where the libstdc++.so is located
 -nostdlib is not specified

Looking forward for your help.

Comment: The file hciops.c is a C file and it already has stdlib.h included.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

to the file.

Comment: for C++ you should use the `cstdlib` header instead.